# Семилетняя война и холодная война

Tags: прописная

По Лопатину

В названиях исторических эпох и событий, календарных периодов и праздников с прописной буквы пишется первое слово (которое может быть единственным), напр.: Средние века, Крестовые походы, Петровская эпоха, Возрождение (также Раннее Возрождение, Высокое Возрождение ), Ренессанс, Проторенессанс, Реформация, Кватроченто, Смутное время (в России в XVII в.),Варфоломеевская ночь, Бородинское сражение, Куликовская битва, Семилетняя война, Первая мировая война, Вторая мировая война, Гражданская война (в России 1918–1921 гг.); Июльская монархия, Вторая империя, Третья республика (в истории Франции), Парижская коммуна, Война за независимость (в Северной Америке), Декабрьское вооруженное восстание 1905 года, Февральская революция 1917 года (Февраль ), Октябрьская революция (Октябрь ), Жакерия, Медный бунт, Новый год, Первое мая, Международный женский день, День независимости, День учителя, Дни славянской письменности и культуры.

Наверное, сначала писали "холодная война", сейчас - холодная война.

Может ли быть такое, что через какое-то время будут писать - Холодная война?

Answer (score 3):

Вряд ли, потому что это не название войны, а как бы её качество, условное название,поэтому, действительно, писали в кавычках, но сейчас это общепринятое понятие, кавычки не нужны.

Сейчас идёт информационная война, тоже пишется со строчной буквы, это же не название.

Comment: Согласен. "Холодная война" никогда не станет именем собственным уже потому, что никогда не будет привязана к конкретной исторической ситуации. Это характеристика отношений, а не эпохи.

Answer (score 3):

У имени собственного исторической тематики всегда должны быть четкие временные рамки, а названия могут быть разные, в том числе и условными (Медный бунт и др.).

Answer (score 1):

В научной литературе по истории XX в. и сейчас уже зачастую пишут Холодная война [пример 1](http://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/sssr-i-holodnaya-voyna-1945-1953-gg), [пример 2](http://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/sovremennaya-otechestvennaya-istoriografiya-holodnoy-voyny), [пример 3](http://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/avstriyskiy-vopros-v-holodnoy-voyne-1945-1955-gg), если имеют в виду вполне конкретное противостояние между СССР и США во второй половине XX в. Даты этой войны достаточно условны и спорны, поэтому я их не указываю, наиболее распространённые - это 1946-1991 гг., но по мне более логичными выглядят даты 1962-1989 гг.

Если под холодной войной подразумевается способ конфронтации, а не конкретное событие, то заглавная буква в этом случае не нужна.